# Pass a PHP variable to jquery ajax post function stored in another js file

Tags: php, jquery

For example I have a variable `$abc`. I want to somehow pass it to the jQuery AJAX POST function which is stored in another JS file. The post function will pass that variable to `page2.php` and this page will use it to query database and finally display the content of `page2.php` on the current page.

So how do I actually pass the `$abc` variable to the jQuery post function which is in an external JS file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `data-*` attributes to achieve this. In your HTML, you can add that attribute with the `$abc` PHP variable:

```html
<a href="#" data-var="<?php echo $abc ?>">Foo</a>
```

Then in your external JS file, you can read this attribute from the element which raised the event and include it in the AJAX data:

```js
$('a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: '/bar/',
        data: {
            foobar: $(this).data('var')
        }
    });
});
```